Ctrl-x Ctrl-e bash how to edit previous multiline command
In bash want to re-edit a multiline command (that I invoked previously) with Ctrl-x Ctrl-e. This will open vim (for me) and letting me type the command. Now with all the bells and whistles set (ref):
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -s lithist
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '

it still doesn't work. For example when I press Ctrl-x Ctrl-e to open the command buffer in vim and type:
echo "Hello"
echo "World"

in the command editor, save / execute, it will treat each line as a seperate history entry! This is apparent when I try to Ctrl-p through the history. However I want them to flock together as one history entry and also persist that on disk. When I look at .bash_history I see this:
#1734086162
echo "Hello"
#1734086162
echo "World"

This means that two seperate entries were created. However I wanted this:
#1734086162
echo "Hello"
echo "World"

If I manually adapt it it works, I can then Ctrl-p to the entry and edit it as a whole with Ctrl-x Ctrl-e. But how to save it as a multiline command automatically?
My bash version is
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)


How is the shell supposed to know that you consider two distinct single-line commands as a single command?

Well they're executed at the same time? I don't press  between the two. If I edit with Ctrl-x Ctrl-e then I get the opportunity to insert multiline commands and execute in one go.

aside: When you write a for loop, for eg. "for x in 1 2" "do" "echo $x" "done" (one per line), then your history becomes "for x in 1 2 ; do echo $x ; done".

Yes it behaves differently for a for loop than for commands that don't span multiple lines somehow

If I type echo A \ + Enter + echo B + Enter, then I get echo A ; echo B in the history

@Fravadona That works yes, but when I do it from vim it doesn't escape the newline. I think that's why it fails.

You need to combine your commands into a Compound Command.
For example in your editor, use a grouping construct
{
echo foo
echo bar
}

And then you'll see something like { echo foo; echo bar; } in your history.
You could also use a logical operator like echo foo && echo bar

That works and is only mildly inconvenient. Accepted :)
